# Unable to input data in to mysql from cloned forms?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am using cloned form from this reference
http://tristandenyer.com/using-jquery-to-duplicate-a-section-of-a-form-maintaining-accessibility/ .
I am trying to enter from the cloned forms in to mysql. Sorry I am a newbie. I am pasting my code below. I am kind of sure that my mistake is in accessing the multidimensional array from php. IN my php code right now I am just trying to print the data to screen. It gives my ample error messages.
This is my html code:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" id="sign-up_area" role="form">
<label class="label_ttl control-label" for="title">Title:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="select_ttl form-control" name="form[0][0]" id="title">
          <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select your title</option>
          <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
          <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
          <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
          <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
          <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
        </select> 
      </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label_fn control-label" for="first_name">First name:</label>
      <input id="first_name" name="form[0][1]" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control" required>
      <p class="help-block">This field is required.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label_ln control-label" for="last_name">Last name:</label>
      <input id="last_name" name="form[0][2]" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_ln form-control">
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label_email control-label" for="email_address">Email:</label>
      <input id="email_address" name="form[0][3]" type="text" placeholder="example@example.com" class="input_email form-control">
    </div>

    <!-- Prepended text-->
    <label class="label_twt control-label" for="institution">Enter Institution / Organization:</label>
    <div class="input-group form-group">

      <input id="twitter_handle" name="form[0][4]" class="input_twt form-control" placeholder="" type="text">
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->



    </div><!-- end #entry1 -->
    <!-- Button (Double) -->
    <p>
    <button type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-info">add section</button>
      <button type="button" id="btnDel" name="btnDel" class="btn btn-danger">remove section above</button>
    </p>





    <!-- Button -->
    <p>
      <button id="submit_button" name="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </p>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

This is my php code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['form'])){
      echo "reaching the else";
$food=$_POST['form'];
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
      for($j=0; $j<3; $j++){
        $car=array($food[$i][$j]=>array($food[$i][$j]));
        //echo $car;
      }
   }
```

This is my javascript code:

```
     $(function () {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
            newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

    /*  This is where we manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new, cloned element
        Below are examples of what forms elements you can clone, but not the only ones.
        There are 2 basic structures below: one for an H2, and one for form elements.
        To make more, you can copy the one for form elements and simply update the classes for its label and input.
        Keep in mind that the .val() method is what clears the element when it gets cloned. Radio and checkboxes need .val([]) instead of .val('').
    */
        // H2 - section
        newElem.find('.heading-reference').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').html('Co-PI #' + newNum);

        // Title - select
        newElem.find('.label_ttl').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum);
        newElem.find('.select_ttl').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'ID' + newNum).val('');

        // First name - text
        newElem.find('.label_fn').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum);
        newElem.find('.input_fn').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'ID' + newNum).val('');

        // Last name - text
        newElem.find('.label_ln').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum);
        newElem.find('.input_ln').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'ID' + newNum).val('');

        // Skate - radio and upload file
       // newElem.find('.label_vitae').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_uploadfile');
       // newElem.find('.btn-primary').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_uploadfile').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_uploadfile').val([]);

        // Email - text
        newElem.find('.label_email').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum);
        newElem.find('.input_email').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'ID' + newNum).val('');

        // Twitter handle (for Bootstrap demo) - append and text
        newElem.find('.label_twt').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum);
        newElem.find('.input_twt').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum).attr('name', 'ID' + newNum).val('');

    // Insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();

    // Enable the "remove" button. This only shows once you have a duplicated section.
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

    // Right now you can only add 4 sections, for a total of 5. Change '5' below to the max number of sections you want to allow.
        if (newNum == 5)
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit"); // value here updates the text in the 'add' button when the limit is reached 
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function () {
    // Confirmation dialog box. Works on all desktop browsers and iPhone.
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section? This cannot be undone."))
            {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
                // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#entry' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {$(this).remove();
                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                    if (num -1 === 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "add section");});
            }
        return false; // Removes the last section you added
    });
    // Enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
    // Disable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on my computer right now, but from looking over your code do you ever actually **start** the form?

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

If not, then this may be what is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have that, sorry for the confusion, just edited.

        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" id="sign-up_area" role="form">